# How to create a new port in Framework7 CLI Cordova?

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I've several Cordova projects.
When I installed all this, I didn’t understand very well what I was doing.
Now I always have some kind of project on the localhost:8080 and I don’t know how to stop it.
When I run the project from the folder. I can not open it (I did't see it).

```
npm run dev
```

How can I change the port to start a new project?
Is it possible to stop the project at port 8080?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy! 
Go to the /build folder in your framework7 project in webpack.config.js add the lines in devServer like this:

```
 devServer:{
  hot:true,
  //host: 'your ip', /* it's optional */
  port:80,
```

In my case, i set the ip and create a one entry A in cloudflare to test over ssl.